# Making only the content scrollable while other two components are fixed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a website where I only need one part of the web scrollable and others to stay fixed. For example, the About Us page should have navigation and left-side panel fixed, while the other content on the page would be scrollable. How to do this?

I have tried to include Navigation and that left-side panel (let's call it Information) into every single component of my page. But this seems to be not a solution. Also, I have tried to include Navigation and Information components into Router element, but when doing this, the layout doesn't function properly, since those two elements have position: fixed in my case.

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Information from './Information';

const AboutPage = () => (
  <div>
    <Information />
    <Navigation />
    <section className='about'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='about__content'>
          <h1>About page</h1>
          <p>
            Irure amet occaecat nostrud dolor aliquip est
            sint laborum eiusmod. Irure do nostrud nulla
            esse do incididunt ad proident nostrud. Labore
            culpa ullamco labore qui deserunt ad proident
            veniam. Adipisicing excepteur ex aliqua
            cupidatat irure aliquip.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
);

export default AboutPage;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Information = () => (
  <div className='information'>
    <h2>Let us know about spreading diseases.</h2>
    <h1>Report it.</h1>
    <p>sveikata.lt</p>
  </div>
);

export default Information;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = () => (
  <nav className='navigation'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink to='/'>about</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to='/report'>report</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Set `max-height` and `overflow-y: scroll` to the component, which you want to be scrollable, also be sure to make the height smaller, so the content will overflow the lower end

Comment: But if i want to include Navigation and Information components on every page, how I should do that? Because the styling breaks then.

Comment: If you want it on every site, consider using it outside of `Switch` component of `react-router-dom` to make it visible on every site

Comment: Okay, I fixed this issue. But a new one has risen. Every page seems to be okay, but ReportPage has a little annoying bug. When you open it, the width of the component changes a bit. I am not sure why is it so, tried every single way that has come to my mind, but didn't find solution. I will paste github link of my project if someone needs more context.   https://github.com/GvidasP/sveikata

Comment: try looking on it with an Inspector (F10 or so in browser), also, I also every time do `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` inside of CSS to ensure correct width

Comment: I can assure you that box-sizing is set to border-box. While checking the page with Inspector, every single page has the same width everywhere, but the one in particular doesn't. If I make the container height: 100%, the problem magically disappears, but then the page becomes scrollable, which is not the result I am looking for.

Comment: probably that's an issue of the scrollbar, you need to make width a little bit smaller, because sidebar overflows over the end

Comment: I didn't use ```{ overflow-y: scroll }``` so there's no scrollbar. I recommend you to open the code and have a look :)